# how to handle same form on different pages (DRY)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I have a template called `base.html`. it contains a fixed search form at top of it. all of my other templates inherit from `base.html`. I want to my form works on every pages (right now I have 10 different pages).

One silly solution is to handle form for every single view, but it is opposite of DRY.

So how can I handle my form one time for all of views ?

NOTE: base.html is just a template and is not used directly by a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate app for 'search' and need to create views and templates accordingly.

I have an app called 'Products' in my Django project and it has the model called 'Product' and I use search to search from that model.

search/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from products.models import Product

class SearchProductView(ListView):
    template_name = "search/view.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchProductView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context['query'] = query
        # SearchQuery.objects.create(query=query)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        method_dict = request.GET
        query = method_dict.get('q', None) # method_dict['q']
        if query is not None:
            return Product.objects.search(query)
        return Product.objects.featured()
        '''
        __icontains = field contains this
        __iexact = fields is exactly this
        '''
```

search/templates/view.html (to render the search results):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
 <div class='row  mb-3'>
            {% if query %}
            <div class='col-12' >
                Results for <b>{{ query }}</b>
                <hr/>
            </div>
            {% else %}

            <div class='col-12 col-md-6 mx-auto py-5'>
               {% include 'search/snippets/search-form.html' %}

            </div>
            <div class='col-12'>
                <hr>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
</div>


        <div class='row'>



    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <div class='col'>

        {% include 'products/snippets/card.html' with instance=obj %}  

        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
         </div> </div><div class='row'><div class='col-12'><hr/></div>
        {% elif forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
            </div> </div><div class='row'><div class='col-12'><hr/></div>
        {% else %}
         </div>  
        {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

search/templates/snippets/search-form.html:

```
<form method='GET' action='{% url "search:query" %}' class="form my-2 my-lg-0 search-form">
  <div class='input-group'>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" name='q' aria-label="Search" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
    <span class='input-group-btn'>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and, finally, urls.py for search app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import (
        SearchProductView
        )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SearchProductView.as_view(), name='query'),
]
```

and include this in your main urls.py:

```
url(r'^search/', include("search.urls", namespace='search')),
```

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: creating an app just for a form does not seems wise answer. anyway thank you.

Comment: @put-video one of the key ideas for a reusable application is: Do one thing and do it well